# ExtJS - get values from form (based on login app tutorial)

Tags: extjs

I've created simple application with official login application tutorial:
[Click Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/tutorials/login_app.html)

App works fine. But it lacks any kind of password checking and I've decided to mess with it a little. Here lies the problem - how to get values from defined form inside controller?

To be more precise, I'd like to get in "onLoginClick" listener.

View:

```
Ext.define('TutorialApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [
        'TutorialApp.view.login.LoginController',
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    controller: 'login',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Login Window',
    closable: false,
    autoShow: true,

    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        reference: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'username',
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password',
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            allowBlank: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            hideEmptyLabel: false,
            value: 'Enter any non-blank password'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login',
            formBind: true,
            listeners: {
                click: 'onLoginClick'
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('TutorialApp.view.login.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.login',

    onLoginClick: function () {
        // get values here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onLoginClick` function you have access to the form via `me.up('window').down('form').getForm()` which can be used as an ajax call (or submit of the form) to verify the user:

```
onLoginClick: function(me) {
    var form = me.up('window').down('form').getForm();
    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            url: 'checkcredentials.php',  // your url
            params: null, // needed for additional params
            submitEmptyText: false,  // don't post empty text in fields
            success: function(form, action) {
               Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
            },
            failure: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So it was all about function parameter instead of "this". Now it works excellent. What is the "me" param - button component instance?

Comment: Yes. It refers to the clicked button.